# (Mysql) Using Memory engine for 4.3 million row table?

Tags: mysql, index, optimization, update, storage-engine

My new company stores an intermediate data for our loading process in a table using the memory engine. However a quite simple update (set a.id=b.id) is taking something like six hours to run.

I've checked how big the tables are and in this import they have a about 4.3 million rows of data in them. I'm certain the problem is the memory engine and the lack of index on id (there is a PK but its across 5 other attributes) based on HASH.

I'm 95% certain I need to change the table engine and index type but I want to make sure before I push for the change.

EDIT: Here is the statement that is is so slow:

```
select  @Extraction_id := id from extraction;

update items as a
set a.extraction_id=@Extraction_id;
```

Edit 2: create statement of table

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `extraction_id` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `a` char(6) NOT NULL,
  `b` char(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `c` date NOT NULL,
  `d` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `e` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `f` decimal(17,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `g` decimal(17,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `h` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY     (`id`,`extraction_id`,`a`,`b`,`c,`d`),
  KEY `fk_extraction` (`extraction_id`),
) ENGINE=MEMORY AUTO_INCREMENT=2343054016 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Looks like that updates all 4.3 million rows of the table??  That's a costly task, and it often implies faulty schema design.

Comment: @RickJames across 3 different tables two of them are these massive tables which takes forever to process.

Comment: As RickJames said that is a costly operation. Why would you need to update 4 million rows, with the same extraction_id? You have your `@Extraction_id` value from the previous select. Just use it where you need it, don't update million of rows with it.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes but the problem is this query sits in a file that checks that the extraction id hasn't been used before in the production database, if it has it gives it a new one but this means it has to update all of the other tables that have the same conflicting extraction id. The extraction id is set outside of SQL on the raw csv's we get so we have to change it in code.

Comment: I still don't understand why you have to update all the rows of the table. If the id had been used, why insert 4 million rows with that id in the first place (and not insert them with the new one)? Or even better, don't have an `extraction_id` in that `items` table at all. This looks more like a design issue, as Rick has pointed.

Comment: Because there can be situations where the same extraction id has been used its created on the timestamp when the extraction was run (some sources run data at the same time) so we need to update the extraction_id to something that hasn't been used yet. Is this stupid, probably but I'm stuck with it.

Comment: @Exostrike - And you are stuck with it being very slow.  InnoDB needs to copy each row that changes -- this is in case of a crash or explicit `ROLLBACK`.  So, imagine the effort taken to copy 4.3 million rows, one by one.  Without keeping a copy, you fall prey to a serious flaw in MyISAM -- A crash in the middle of an `UPDATE` leaves an _unknown_ number of rows updated.

Comment: @RickJames Yeah well the wait for the updates has cleared. I'm planning to bypass this entire procedure by moving this entire check to before the data is loaded into SQL at the file stage using python to prevent this happening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENGINE=MEMORY` is not designed for big tables.  `InnoDB` is well designed for virtually all use cases; switch to it.

It sounds like you need more than an `ENGINE` and index type change.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables, and the statement that is so slow.

`set a.id=b.id`?? -- By convention, DBAs call the `PRIMARY KEY` `id`.  It is very strange to be setting the PK of one table to the PK of another.

**Chunking**

One approach to `UPDATEing` 4M rows will less impact is to "chunk" up the problem.  I discuss details [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).

Comment: "set a.id=b.id" is part of the processes clash checking where if  the ID has already been used before it creates a new one and applies to to the various import tables.

Comment: I've tested using InnoDB on a test database using 1m rows and InnoDB takes even longer, so I'm not sure thats going to save us.

Comment: "ENGINE=MEMORY is not designed for big tables" - in mos serious scenarios you would not consider this a large table. Is MySql really that limited? In Memory Storage is used with hundreds of gigabytes RAM by competitors.

Comment: "It is very strange to be setting the PK of one table to the PK of another." - no. Horizontal partitioning (splitting fields of a logical table to multiple database tables) is one valid scenario. They obviously all share the same ID key. One of them will be leading (mandatory). I use this quite regularly.

Comment: @TomTom - And I recommend it -- but only rarely.  I am wondering if this is an "over-simplification" of the _real_ problem.  And one of those `id's` is not really spelled `id`.